# Matrix within equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, matrices, setspace

I am having some difficulty getting this to display properly.

```
 \begin{equation}
{\bf H} = -{\bf \mu} \cdot {\bf B} = - \gamma B_o {\bf S}_z = -\frac{\gamma B_o\hbar}{2} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
```

Which appears as,

[image: Ugly looking equation]

I would like the matrix height to be consistant with the rest of the equation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Judging from the picture you seem to be using some `setspace` command or `\linespread` for increasing the leading. Can you confirm? By the way, avoid `{\bf H}` that should be `\mathbf{H}`.

Comment: Yes I am using setspace throughout my document. Thank you for the \mathbf{} tip!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\doublespacing
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1}}% return to singlespacing

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H} = -\mathbf\mu \cdot \mathbf{B} = -\gamma B_o \mathbf{S}_z = -\frac{\gamma B_o\hbar}{2} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to use `\boldsymbol{\mu}` instead of `\mathbf{\mu}`.

Comment: You get `Command \normalsize invalid in math mode` at *every* display, which could be annoying.

Answer (score 11):

I'd modify the `\env@matrix` command, on which all the matrix constructions are built;

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for this example

\makeatletter
\def\env@matrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \linespread{1}\selectfont
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
\makeatother

\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H} =
 -\bm{\mu} \cdot \mathbf{B} =
 - \gamma B_o \mathbf{S}_z = -\frac{\gamma B_o\hbar}{2}
 \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Try also without `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}`, that I added in order to space out a bit the rows, which seems better with `\doublespacing`.

Actually, it's difficult to improve something using `\doublespacing`, which destroys any attempt at good typography.

[image]

---

In what does this differ from Mico's and Herbert's methods?

Mico's workaround works only within `equation`. Herbert's instead applies single spacing to *all* display environments, so also to `align`, for instance, reducing the line spacing between aligned equations.
This might be desirable or not, it depends on you.

---

Note that `{\bf H}` should not be used, preferring `\mathbf{H}`. Also, you'll have noticed that `{\bf \mu}` doesn't embolden the mu; use `\bm{\mu}` and load the `bm` package as in my code.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `etoolbox` package and use its `\AtBeginEnvironment` command to reset spacing to `\singlespacing` at the start of an `equation` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace} % per the OP's information provided in a comment
\doublespacing
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\singlespacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H} = -\boldsymbol{\mu} \cdot \mathbf{B} = - \gamma B_o \mathbf{S}_z = -\frac{\gamma B_o\hbar}{2} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Remark: This method is quite simple if only the `equation` environment has to be fixed; it becomes tedious quickly if lots of different display-math environments occur in your document.

Answer (score 0):

Well I thought there would be a simple (inelegant) answer and there is! Simply switch to singlespaceing and add some `\vspace` to make everything hunkydory!

```
Text here. . .Magnetic resonance imaging blah blah Hamiltonian. . .

\vspace{-0.5cm}
\singlespacing
\begin{equation}
{\bf H} = -{\bf \mu} \cdot {\bf B} = - \gamma B_o {\bf S}_z = -\frac{\gamma B_o\hbar}{2} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}.
\vspace{0.5cm}
\end{equation}
\doublespacing
```

Thanks egreg for your comments! **Note: egreg** warns that this may cause the equation to move to the top of the next page, which is a big no no. Thus, this quick fix may not be the solution for everyone.

[image: Fixed!]

Comment: You probably are leaving a blank line before the equation, which is wrong.

Comment: Leaving a blank line before an equation means that the equation can end up at the top of the next page, which is a typographic sin worse than leaving a widow line.

Comment: @egreg and Shinobii: it would be good to clean up and to remove the comments after the issue in the comments is solved. If there's a texnical value in the comments, it could be moved into the answer.