# Parentheses of matrix too big

Tags: matrices

I am trying to type a matrix, but the parentheses looks bigger. How can I make the parentheses fit?

It looks like the problem is caused by the doublespacing, but I want the double spacing for the text. How can I get around this?

Below is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\rho=
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{00} & \rho_{01}\\
\rho_{10} & \rho_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. A complete (yet minimal) example might be useful, it doesn't look like that in `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\rho=
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{00} & \rho_{01}\\
\rho_{10} & \rho_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I do use amsmath package but use a customed class and style. I am not sure which could affect this or how I can override this. Could it possible because the use of setspace package? If needed, I can attach the .sty file

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Since you haven't even told us *which* "customised class and style" you are using, do you expect people to read your mind to find out? Unless you provide a *complete* and *runnable* small example that shows the problem, nobody can help you fix it!

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you're using double spacing; I believe the problem has already appeared on the site.

Comment: Ugly workaround: `{\singlespacing\begin{equation}...\end{equation}}`.  Alternatively, `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\singlespacing}`, as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137004/matrix-within-equation/137008#137008

Comment: @egreg - Indeed, it's a duplicate -- see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137009/5001) in  particular. :-)

Comment: Whatever else you do, be sure to specify the option `nodisplayskipstretch` when loading the `setspace` package.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned problem doesnot happen if we use the standard tagging, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\rho=
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{00} & \rho_{01}\\
\rho_{10} & \rho_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

So the problem might be related with your customized class file, also if we use the package with double spacing option like "`\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}`" as suggested by one of a great `egreg` then the same problem happened with this code also, so better check and remove the `setspace` package from your class file and try...

Comment: Remove doublespacing will address the problem but how can I get around this if I need doublespacing for the text. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to increase the leading space alone then use the tag \addtolength{\baselineskip}{3pt} and if you want to increase both fontsize and leading then use the tag as \fontsize{13}{17}\selectfont at the preamble part