# More and Less Space in Cases

Tags: spacing, cases

[image]

Why do I have this space (red arrow)? Why I do not have more space (orange arrow)?

I use `cases` and `doublespacing`.

Even I use `\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1}}`, because of `doublespacing`, as suggested in [Matrix within equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137004/matrix-within-equation), the problem does not solve.

I have tried `array`, `dcases`, `drcases`, but it does not work.

Thank you!

Comment: @Mico I have not issued any command `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{2}`. I use the harvard-thesis.cls and I use `doublespacing`.

Comment: Ah, the piece of information related to the use of the `setspace` package and the `\doublespacing` directive is absolutely crucial.

Comment: You should study the query [Matrix within equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137004/5001) and, in particular,  the answer provided by Herbert, *viz*., issuing the instruction `\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1}}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have some symmetry using `\bigstrut` but you get a better result with some caution loading `empheq` and using the eponymous environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{empheq, bigstrut}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
With \texttt{ dcases: }
\[\begin{cases}
    x + y = q^2 \\
    \biggl[\dfrac{N}{q^2}\biggr]_{\bigstrut[b]} x + \biggl(\biggl[\dfrac{N}{q^2}\biggr] + 1\biggr)y = N
  \end{cases} \]%

With \verb|\empheqlbrace:| 
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
  & x + y = q^2\\
  & \biggl[\dfrac{N}{q^2}\biggr]x + \biggl(\biggl[\dfrac{N}{q^2}\biggr]_{\bigstrut[b]} + 1\biggr)y = N
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the OP has revealed a crucial piece of information in the meantime, *viz*., that he/she uses the `setspace` package and a `\doublespacing` directive. Do you want to adjust your answer accordingly?

Comment: @Bernand It works perfect with `\empheqlbrace`. But I need to use `\\[-2.6ex]` instead of `\\[-2ex]` to be symmetric. Maybe because of `\doublespacing` as @Mico said.

Comment: Probably. The exact value has to be found by trial and error. Normally, there would be no correction to do, but here there's a discrepancy between the two rows.

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis:  I've found a better solution, using `bigstrut`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Bernard It is much better! I can also use `align`,`align*` with numbering easier. Thank you!