# Doublespacing from the setspace package stretches matrices?

Tags: spacing, matrices, setspace

I'm writing an article which is doublespaced throughout. Normal math mode looks fine, but in any instance of the `pmatrix` environment, the parentheses of the matrix become stretched out. Roughly, I have something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespace

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

The parentheses then stretch much wider than the matrix entries `a` and `b` and it looks bad to me. How can I make these matrices format normally, while still doublespacing throughout the document?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137009/2388