# Unwanted space in pmatrix environment

Tags: matrices

I am writing my homework using TeX.

Here, I drew a matrix with pmatrix environment.

[image]

As you guys can see, there is unwanted space in top of matrix.

What I want to ask are following two:

1. How can I get rid of these 'unwanted space'
2. How can I reduce spaces between components of this matrix? They are too far each other.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you might be having a problem similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137004/82917

Comment: Mighty crystal~~ Thanks!